# How to archive same jquery action for multiple div container without conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple Div container each container have a list .

The first five results of list items should be visible next list items should be visible on scroll.

when user click on "showmore" the scrollbar will be disabled and all the list items  would be visible without scrollbar.

If list items does not have less than four results the show more link will be hide.

We  archive the same as an one container list items but i want to use same script for all the div container list items.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/16my4pap/11/)**

**HTML:**

```
<h1>First part</h1>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-down">Arrow</span></a>
    <span class="fb_options_head">Heading 1</span>

    <!--Hiding Div Start-->
    <div id="demo" class="collapse in">

      <ul class="nav_accordian">
        <li>One
          <ul>
            <li>on 1.1</li>
            <li>on 1.2</li>
            <li>on 1.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
      </ul>
      <p class="showMore">Show More</p>
    </div>
    <!--Hiding Div End-->

  </div>
</div>
<h1>Second part</h1>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <a href="#demo1" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-down">Arrow</span></a>
    <span class="fb_options_head">Heading 2</span>

    <!--Hiding Div Start-->
    <div id="demo1" class="collapse in">

      <ul class="nav_accordian">
        <li>One
          <ul>
            <li>on 1.1</li>
            <li>on 1.2</li>
            <li>on 1.3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
      </ul>
      <p class="showMore">Show More</p>
    </div>
    <!--Hiding Div End-->

  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.nav_accordian').each(function() {
  var max = 4
  if ($(this).find('> li').length > max) {

    $(".showMore").show();
  } else {
    $(".showMore").hide();
  }
  $('.showMore').click(function() {
  alert("call");
    $('.nav_accordian').toggleClass("fullAuto");
    $(".showMore").text(function(_, txt) {
      return txt == "Show More" ? "Less More" : "Show More";
    })
  });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav_accordian {
  max-height: 160px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

.fullAuto {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Changes Made**

► Moved the `click` function out of the loop

► Used `$(this)` instead of `$(".showMore")` inside the `click` function

```
$('.nav_accordian').each(function() {
  var max = 4
  if ($(this).find('> li').length > max) {
    $(".showMore").show();
  } else {
    $(".showMore").hide();
  }
});
$('.showMore').click(function() {
  alert("call");
  $(this).prev().toggleClass("fullAuto");
  $(this).text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt == "Show More" ? "Less More" : "Show More";
  })
});
```

**[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16my4pap/14/)**